# Rotate a shape in Google Slides without rotating the text

Tags: text-formatting, google-slides

I've used PowerPoint almost all my life - have used Star/Open/Libre Office Presentations as well without much issue. I'm relatively new at using Google Slides.

Here's what I want:
I'm using the built in shape "Flow Chart Offpage Connector". Basically, a rectangle with a triangle pointing down. I have it rotated 270 degrees so it points right instead of down. I want to add text to this shape. When I add it, the letters are sideways and going from bottom to top due to the rotation. I want the letters to appear normal orientation and go left to right. How do I do that?

This seems like it should be an easy, straight forward answer but I can't find it.

Comment: Google slides won't allow you to do that however in this case the Shape > Arrows > Pentagon will solve your problem.  You simply need to squash it a bit to match the "Flow Chart Offpage Connector" then they are identical but the text is oriented as you wish. [@Neil's answer is the way to go](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/162663/163914#163914)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate text box and rotate that, then move it onto the shape. You can then group the two to create something to move around.

Comment: Your method works but is not what the op wants: a way to rotate text associated with the shape, as is possible in other presentation tools such as Powerpoint or Keynote. Unfortunately, this is not possible in Google Slides right now. You could edit your answer to reflect the impossibility (and keep the rest as is).

Answer (score -1):

For most shapes, you should either be able to reshape it to point in another direction, or choose a different shape that's the same except pointing in a different direction.

Comment: Please [edit] to add additional details that will explain how this addresses the orientation of the text when rotating the shape, and provide support for your point that there are duplicate shapes to the one being used that point in different directions and will; address the text orientation problem.